# Posts are duplicating on wp_post_update

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, page-template, wp-update-post

I have stucked in writing a simple function that on certain page update refresh all posts in a custom post type.

Here is my code (based on [this](http://kakoma.ug/code/2013/09/wordpress-tutorial-update-posts-category/)):

```
add_action('save_post', 'bulk_refresh');
function bulk_refresh($post_id) {
    if($post_id != 123)//123 is the 'certain page' id
        return;
    $posts_to_update = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'MY_CUSTOM_TYPE', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
    while($posts_to_update ->have_posts()) : $posts_to_update ->the_post();
        $args = array( 'ID' => $post->ID );
        wp_update_post( $args );
    endwhile;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

On first sight all must be working fine, but when I save the page with id '123' all posts in the custom post type are duplicated. I want just to 'refresh' them.

Any ideas where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found the answer myself. I've added global $post before the loop and now all seems to works fine. I don't know if this is a good practice, so if you have another ideas share them :)

Here is the revised code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'bulk_refresh');
function bulk_refresh($post_id) {
if($post_id != 123)//123 is the 'certain page' id
    return;
global $post;
$posts_to_update = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'MY_CUSTOM_TYPE', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
while($posts_to_update ->have_posts()) : $posts_to_update ->the_post();
    $args = array( 'ID' => $post->ID );
    wp_update_post( $args );
endwhile;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```